# Intuition for why a change of basis matrix can be found this way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse, change-of-basis

I have been learning about transformation matrices and change of basis in my lectures recently. The concepts aren't new to me and I thought/think I had a good intuition for it. However, I am currently very confused.

The context is as follows: Consider we have two coordinate Systems $S$ and $S'$ and a vector $\vec v$. Let $v_ie_i$ be the coordinates of $\vec v$ in $S$ and $v_i'e_i'$ its coordinates in $S'$, where $e_i$ and $e_i'$ are the coordinates of the basis vectors of each coordinate system in $S$. Let's suppose we know the coordinates of $\vec v$ in $S$ and we know the coordinates of $e_i'$ in $S$. We want to know the coordinates of $\vec v$ in $S'$.

Here's what I'd do: If we write the coordinates of the basis vectors of $S'$ in our coordinate system as a matrix $A$, then we can multiply $\vec v$ (using its coordinates in $S$) with the inverse $A^{-1}$ of that matrix. The result will be the coordinates of $\vec v$ in $S'$. I have an intuitive understanding of why this works, mainly because of the 3b1b [video](https://youtu.be/P2LTAUO1TdA) on this topic.

Here's the procedure we followed in my lecture. We find the matrix to multiply $\vec v$ with by finding the scalar products of $e_i$ and $e_i'$ such that for a 2D matrix the result has the form

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}e_1'\cdot e_1&e_1'\cdot e_2\\e_2'\cdot e_1&e_2'\cdot e_2\end{pmatrix}$$

In our example, it was obvious to me why the resulting matrix gives the coordinates of $e_i$ in $S'$ (or the inverse of $A$), but I don't feel like I understand why and how it works. I see that this procedure gives us two new basis vectors

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}x \text{ component of }e_1'\\x \text{ component of }e_2'\end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad b=\begin{pmatrix}y \text{ component of }e_1'\\y \text{ component of }e_2'\end{pmatrix}$$

but I'm unable to see why this is equal to the coordinates of the basis vectors of $S$ in $S'$.

It would be great if someone could clarify this, preferably, but not required intuitively.

Comment: _"I'm unable to see why this is equal to the coordinates of the basis vectors of $S$ in $S′$"_, does it help to pick the basis for $S'$ as the standard basis vectors $(1,0,...,0)$, $(0,1,0...,0)$ etc.?

Comment: @Joe it actually does! This way we get the new basis vectors as the x and y components of $e_1$ and $e_2$, just as it should be. Thanks for clearing my confusion! I'd also suggest you put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to help, I'll write this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that your question boils down to you having difficult understanding why $\begin{pmatrix}e_1'\cdot e_1&e_1'\cdot e_2\\e_2'\cdot e_1&e_2'\cdot e_2\end{pmatrix}$ is equal to the coordinates of the basis vectors of $S$ when viewed in the $S'$ frame.

To help get some intuition for this, I advise choosing coordinates such that the basis for $S′$ is $$ e_1'= (1,0,...,0), \qquad e_2' =(0,1,0,...,0), \qquad ... ,\qquad e_n' = (0,...,0,1).$$